# Copying ComboBox string to a TextBox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, textbox

How do I copy information in a combo box to a textbox ?
And i want it done in real time, so once an items is elected in the combo box it appers in the text box

cboGender.SelectedText = txtGender.Text tried that

Comment: Is this VBA or VB.NET?

Comment: First: VBA is not VB.NET so please clarify. Second: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to copy the `Text` from a `ComboBox` to a `TextBox`, the code you supplied is backwards. But the real answer is, don't use `ComboBox.SelectedText`; use `ComboBox.Text`

```
txtGender.Text = cboGender.Text
```

Comment: Thanks alot Dan cant upvote as im a new user but yeah thanks very novice question just stared programming

Comment: No problem @m3rky. By the way, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to view the FAQ @ http://stackoverflow.com/faq and if this answer solved your problem, please click the check to accept it :)

Comment: Wow thanks a lot very helpful website will be using this a lot and have checked the tick its green